# How to merge values in an array by comparing other common field value in that object in Mule

Tags: mule, dataweave, mulesoft

We have an array of objects below, whose fields address1,mobile,nickName are to be concatenated based on other fields value being common.
For example, mobile is an array so when we merge the mobile values from other objects we should append to the array and not have repeated values, same for address1 and nickName, it should be a comma separated string.

Input:

```
[{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["12345","45678"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Park Avenue-879",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["65789","45678"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mic",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["89065","67895"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["36926","85931"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
}
]
```

Expected Output:

```
[{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314,Park Avenue-879",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["12345","45678","65789"], 
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike,Mic",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["89065","67895"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "true",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["36926","85931"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
}
]
```

From above expected response, in input "45678" is repeated in both objects so only once it is updated in result and also 2nd object is not merged with the first set because field active has diff value.

Comment: `"nickName": "Mike","Mic",` this is not valid JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Try this if it helps

```
%dw 2.0

// Function to compare values of two objects
fun compareValues(accObj, inObj) =
    // Compare all the fields of accObj and inObj
    (accObj.city == inObj.city) and
    (accObj.country == inObj.country) and
    (accObj.name == inObj.name) and
    (accObj.postalCode == inObj.postalCode) and
    (accObj.stateOrProvince == inObj.stateOrProvince) and
    (accObj.active == inObj.active) and
    (accObj.dob == inObj.dob)

// Function to check for matching objects in the accumulator array
fun checkForMatching(accArray, inObj) =
    // Filter the accArray to find objects that match with inObj using the compareValues function
    accArray filter ((accObj) -> compareValues(accObj, inObj))

// Function to merge matching objects with updated fields
fun mergeWithMatching(accArray, inObj) =
    accArray map ((accObj) ->
        if(compareValues(accObj, inObj))
            // If the objects match, update specific fields with values from inObj
            accObj  update {
                case aAddress1 at .address1 -> "$(aAddress1),$(inObj.address1)"
                case aMobile at .mobile -> (aMobile ++ inObj.mobile) distinctBy $
                case aNickName at .nickName -> "$(aNickName),$(inObj.nickName)"
        }
        else accObj)

output application/json
---

// Reduce function to merge and update items in the payload
payload reduce ((item, accumulator = []) ->
    if(! isEmpty(checkForMatching(accumulator, item)))
        // If matching items exist in accumulator, merge them with updated fields
        mergeWithMatching(accumulator, item)
    else accumulator << item)
```

Input

```
[{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["12345","45678"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Park Avenue-879",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["65789","45678"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mic",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "false",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
},
{
  "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
  "city": "San Diego",
  "country": "USA",
  "mobile": ["89065","67895"],
  "name": "Michael",
  "nickName": "Mike",
  "postalCode": "1345",
  "stateOrProvince": "CA",
  "active": "true",
  "dob": "1996-05-01"
}]
```

Output

```
[
  {
    "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314,Park Avenue-879",
    "city": "San Diego",
    "country": "USA",
    "mobile": [
      "12345",
      "45678",
      "65789"
    ],
    "name": "Michael",
    "nickName": "Mike,Mic",
    "postalCode": "1345",
    "stateOrProvince": "CA",
    "active": "false",
    "dob": "1996-05-01"
  },
  {
    "address1": "Koala Boulevard-314",
    "city": "San Diego",
    "country": "USA",
    "mobile": [
      "89065",
      "67895"
    ],
    "name": "Michael",
    "nickName": "Mike",
    "postalCode": "1345",
    "stateOrProvince": "CA",
    "active": "true",
    "dob": "1996-05-01"
  }
]
```